# Role of p-value in ruling out null hypothesis

Tags: p-value

My question is about the interpretation of p-value. Under the null hypothesis the p-value is uniformly distributed. Then why does a test statistic landing in the far ends together comprising 5% of probability support ruling out the null hypothesis at 5% confidence when we don't say the same about any other interval.

To make it more concrete take the null hypothesis of a standard normal distribution and divide the number line into 40 equi-probability (under the standard normal) non-overlapping intervals. Why is the test statistic landing in one of the two extremes (with a total of 5% chance under the null hypothesis) rule out the null hypothesis at 5% confidence interval? Why don't we say the same about a combination of any of the $\phantom{a}^{40} C_2$ intervals?

For comparison think of a 40-faced dice. We want to check the null hypothesis of the dice being fare. If we get 1 or 40 would we say at 5% confidence we can say the null hypothesis is ruled out?

Comment: Fisher would say "extreme" was the key word here.  More precisely, you want to use the rejection region which has the most [statistical power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power). You want to minimise [Type II errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors#Type_II_error) where you fail to reject a false null hypothesis

Comment: I think I can see what you are saying for the Gaussian but what about the dice example?

Comment: For your example of a single roll of a $40$-sided die, it might depend on your null hypothesis.  One which said *"all faces are equally likely"* needs more than one roll to have any information which might possibly be seen as "extreme", while one which said *"the expected value of a roll is $20.5$"* could be tested with a single roll in the way you suggest.  This is an example of why some statisticians do not like frequentist hypothesis tests.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure for the second null hypothesis you mention getting a 40 or 1 would rule out the null hypothesis of a expected value of 20.5 at 5% confidence interval according to the methods of frequentist hypothesis testing?

Comment: Not "rule out", but "reject the null hypothesis at a $5\%$ significance level" in the knowledge that when the null hypothesis is true you may have a $5\%$ probability of erroneously rejecting it

Comment: Yeah sorry about the incorrect phrasing. That's what I meant but phrasing can be very important here. Thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choosing any given 5% of the null distribution will leave you with a valid test (in that it will have a 5% significance level) but most people are somewhat concerned that their test not only reject the null that small proportion of the time when $H_0$ is true but that it also have better than a 5% chance to reject $H_0$ when it's *false*.

As a result, people try to consider power in some way when choosing a rejection region (i.e. which 5% - or whatever other $\alpha$ - of the null distribution to reject for). For example:

1. If you have some test statistic and you have a test with some particular kind of alternative you'd normally choose the 5% (the proportion $\alpha$) of the null distribution that's most consistent with the alternative to be the 5% you reject. For example, if you had a permutation test for a difference in means you'd choose the 5% that had the biggest (absolute) difference in means. So when the null was more wrong you would have a better chance to be in the rejection region. This is the general consideration.

   In cases where you have a broader set of alternatives (such as when testing goodness of fit) you would choose a test statistic that in some general sense picks up (/measures) the kinds of alternatives you care about (typically, that it measures discrepancy from the ideal null case -- *lack of fit* -- in some way and so tends to be "large" when the null is false) and then you reject for the most discrepant 5%.
2. If you're doing a likelihood ratio test you choose the 5% of the null distribution where the likelihood ratio $\mathcal{L}_0/\mathcal{L}_1$ is smallest.
3. If you're basing a test off the likelihood itself (as with a Fisher exact test, for example), you'd choose the 5% of the null distribution with the lowest likelihood.